# How to deleteRecord when it was never committed on the backend?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a simple ember-data model (rev 12 -master as of 04/21/2013)

```
App.Foo = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string')
}).reopenClass({
    add: function(json) {
        //call create record but don't commit it
        var store = DS.get('defaultStore');
        store.createRecord(App.Foo, json);
    }
});
```

At some point in my application I need to remove an item from the store so I tried the usual

```
var foo = store.find(App.Foo, 1);
foo.deleteRecord();
```

But because the record is not completely loaded (server side) I get the error

> Uncaught Error: Attempted to handle event `deleteRecord` on
>    while in state rootState.loading. Called with
>   undefined

If I plan to use ember-data in this way how can I "fake" the commit or mark the record as loaded manually?

Comment: can you do `store.find(App.Foo, 1).then(function(data){data.deleteRecord();});`

Comment: in rev 11, i'm using `deleteRecord` all over the place for records that weren't commited, btw. But I usually have a handle on the instance of that record without having to call `find`

Comment: As I am thinking about it, `deleteRecord` should be working too as Mehul is saying. It works for me.

Comment: @ToranBillups This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/bskUT/) may help. I've added something similar in the `ContactsAddRoute`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I am not mistaken you can just do this:

```
var foo = store.find(App.Foo, 1);
foo.transaction.rollback();
```

This way the record will no longer be saved on commit.

Comment: This is not deleting a record, I believe it just stops loading it on the client side

Comment: You do not need to delete record that has never been committed I suppose.

Comment: The record is persisted as it is loaded through `store.find`